# Add PHP value (ACF) to Javascript array in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables

I have this code, which returns the variable `$v`, each `$v` containing a certain string `(for example: icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4)`:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
         var vArr = new array();
        </script>

        <?php
         $field_key = "field_571e2339a3859";
         $field = get_field_object($field_key);
         if( $field )
         {
            foreach( $field['value'] as $k => $v )
            {
                $v = implode('/', $v);
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    vArr.push("<?php echo $v; ?>");
                </script>
            <?php }
         }
         ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
         console.log(vArr[0]);
        </script>
```

The first part creates the javascript array, the second part gives a value to the `$v` variable, and puts it in the array, and the third part returns the first value of the array in the console, for the test.

But I get these two errors:

```
(index):325 Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined
(anonymous function) @ (index):325

(index):328 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
(anonymous function) @ (index):328
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: constructors by convention start with an upper case letter `var vArr = new Array();` is the actual syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using this:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
         var kek;
        </script>

        <?php
         $field_key = "field_571e2339a3859";
         $field = get_field_object($field_key);
         if( $field )
         {
            foreach( $field['value'] as $k => $v )
            {
                $v = implode('/', $v);
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                 kek += "-<?php echo $v; ?>";
                </script>
            <?php }
         }
         ?>
```

It works, but not how I want it to work.

Comment: Well, very simply. There are 7 values (icon1 to icon7). I want to create an if statement, when the name is equal to icon1, show icon1. When the name is equal to icon2, show icon2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var vArr = new Array();
 </script>
```

Comment: Oh god, did I seriously forget to begin with an uppercase? It works now :p

Comment: I cursed my eyes for not noticing it for all that while I was asking wierd questions :P. @MaartenWolfsen